# Coercion of Enums in Nashorn works differently than in Rhino

Tags: java-8, nashorn

It seems that Java enums are no longer coerced into their string value:

```
java.math.RoundingMode.UP == "UP"
```

evaluates to true in Java 7 but to false in Java 8 when executed in the JavaScript engine.

Does anybody know if this is actually a bug or just something in the specification?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072426
.....................................................................

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: No. The link points to the official bugtracking system of Java. This will not go away at leisure. Providing a snapshot of an ongoing discussion about why this is a bug and how it might be fixed adds no value.