# Maximo JS automation script: "importPackage" is not defined

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, package, nashorn, maximo

I'm attempting to use a JS script from Maximo 76 Scripting Features ([PDF download](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/02db2a84-fc66-4667-b760-54e495526ec1/page/03ad118c-6040-43dd-bc6d-d7a03510d135/attachment/1004fd2b-1b51-411e-8df0-a8b02ca86272/media/Scritping76Features%20%285%29.pdf)).

```
importPackage(java.util)
importPackage(Packages.psdi.server)
var ctx = new HashMap();
ctx.put("url","http://localhost:7001/maximo/oslc/script/countryapi?_lid=wilson&_lpwd=wilson");
service.invokeScript("LIB_HTTPCLIENT",ctx);
var jsonResp = ctx.get("response");
var countries = JSON.parse(jsonResp);
```

When I execute the script I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: "importPackage" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
```

**Why am I getting this error?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Add this to the beginning of the script:**

```
load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
```

---

**Details:**

From [Automation Scripts: Compatibility with Maximo 7.6.1](https://a3jgroup.com/automation-scripts-compatibility-with-maximo-7-6-1/):

> ...the Rhino JavaScript engine was replaced with Nashorn (V8).  It
>   turns out that **Nashorn does not permit the import of whole Java
>   packages** which sheds light on why I was getting the error.
>
> Add the following line to the beginning of your script:
>
> **`load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");`**
>
> [This article references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502630/switching-from-rhino-to-nashorn) how to properly construct your script to
>   take advantage of the new script engine.

And from  Maximo 76 Scripting Features ([PDF download](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/02db2a84-fc66-4667-b760-54e495526ec1/page/03ad118c-6040-43dd-bc6d-d7a03510d135/attachment/1004fd2b-1b51-411e-8df0-a8b02ca86272/media/Scritping76Features%20%285%29.pdf)).

> Java 8 and Nashorn engine:
>
> Some of the above example is written using
>   the jdk 7 based rhino js engine. In jdk 1.8, the rhino engine has been
>   replaced with the Nashorn (V8) engine. **For example the importPackage
>   command will not work there.** You would need to use the JavaImporter
>   function to do the same in Nashorn. You can look into this
>   stackoverflow link for more details on what all changed from Rhino to
>   Nashorn that may impact your script code in js:
>
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502630/switching-from-rhino-to-nashorn

Answer (score 1):

According to [Rhino Migration Guide](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Rhino+Migration+Guide) you can try something like this:

```
var HashMap = Java.type("java.util.HashMap");
```

because it works like an import, you can use it afterwards:

```
var ctx = new HashMap();
```