# Run an automation script via a URL

Tags: url, parameters, configuration, integration, maximo

Maximo 7.6.1.1:

I want to run a Maximo automation script by invoking a URL in a separate system.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Related post here: [Invoke autoscript via URL to create WO](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/iot/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=a78c727b-d54d-4b8f-b47c-0c2a03469d27&CommunityKey=3d7261ae-48f7-481d-b675-a40eb407e0fd&tab=digestviewer#bma78c727b-d54d-4b8f-b47c-0c2a03469d27)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great use-case and something that we've been working through in the last few days.

1. Create automation script. - mine is called automation_api_test
2. Manually invoke it through the API using a browser to make sure that you can actually get it to run. (%servername%/maximo/oslc/script/automation_api_test?var1=1212321232&var2=1555&site=OPS&_lid=wilson&_lpwd=wilson)
3. Script it like you would your regular automation script. Here's one that can read in a few parameters from the URL and use those to perform operations in the core system.

   ```
   importPackage(Packages.psdi.server);
   importPackage(Packages.psdi.util.logging);

   var resp = {};
   // Get the Site ID from the Query Parameters
   //var site = request.getQueryParam("site");

   var var1 = request.getQueryParam("var1");
   var var2 = request.getQueryParam("var2");
   var site = request.getQueryParam("site");
   //var zxqponum = request.getQueryParam("ponum");

   //logger.debug(zxqprinter);
   service.log("TESTING script Params" + request.getQueryParams());   
   service.log("var1 " + request.getQueryParam("var1"));
   service.log("var2 " + request.getQueryParam("var2"));

   //count the number of WO's in the site
   var woset = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("WORKORDER", request.getUserInfo());
   woset.setQbe("SITEID","="+site);
   var woCount = woset.count();
   resp.wo_count = woCount;
   woset.close();

   // Get Total Count
   resp.total = woCount;
   //create the response - still not sure why I had to append the vars to a string.

   resp.var1= "" + var1;
   resp.var2= "" + var2;
   resp.site= "" + site;

   var responseBody = JSON.stringify(resp);
   ```

Comment: Normally you append variables to a string to cast the type of the variable to string. I haven't looked it up, but I expect `request.getQueryParam()` may return a `byte[]` not a Javascript string.

Comment: Related article here: https://a3jgroup.com/call-maximo-automation-scripts-from-json-api/

Answer (score 0):

*Here's an expanded version of Kasey's answer.*

**Create a sample automation script in Maximo:**

1. Automation Scripts >> More Actions >> Create >> Script
2. Script [name]: HELLOWORLD
3. Script Language: js
4. Paste in this code:

---

```
//THIS IS JAVASCRIPT! NOT JYTHON!

//load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js"); //More info about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537142/maximo-js-automation-script-importpackage-is-not-defined

//importPackage(Packages.psdi.server);
//importPackage(Packages.psdi.util.logging);
    
var resp = {};
var var1 = request.getQueryParam("var1");

resp.var1= " " + var1 + " World!";
var responseBody = JSON.stringify(resp);
```

5. Click *Create*

---

**Try out a URL:**

*This URL will send the word "Hello" to the automation script. The automation script will append the word " World!" onto "Hello".*

*The phrase, "Hello World!" is returned.*

6. In a browser, run this URL: http://yourhostname:1234/maximo/oslc/script/helloworld?var1=Hello&_lid=wilson&_lpwd=wilson

- Replace `yourhostname` with your host name
- Replace `1234` with your port number
- Replace `maximo` with the appropriate value.

7. The URL request should return this JSON object to the browser:

**`{"var1":" Hello World!"}`**

8. From there, create a hyperlink in a separate system (using the above URL). And click it to run the automation script.

- *If the last line in the script were to be deleted, nothing would be returned to the browser.*

---

**Note:**

The URL only seems to work for me under the WILSON user. It doesn't work with my own user:

```
{"oslc:Error":{"oslc:statusCode":"401","spi:reasonCode":"BMXAA7901E","oslc:message":
"You cannot log in at this time. Contact the system administrator.","oslc:extendedError"
:{"oslc:moreInfo":{"rdf:resource":"http:\/\/something\/maximo\/oslc\
/error\/messages\/BMXAA7901E"}}}}
```

Best guess is: my user is not set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple JavaScript example:

```
responseBody = "asdf";
```

[image]

Then just run the URL in a browser (or somewhere else like an automation script in Maximo or a Python script in GIS).

```
https://<<my host>>/maximo/oslc/script/testscript
```

[image]

---

It's pretty much the same for Python (no semi-colon):

```
responseBody = "asdf"
```