# Automated way to create packages and deploy to environments in maximo migration manager

Tags: maximo

Maximo is an IBM tool.
You use the maximo Migration Manager set of applications to promote product configuration content from one product environment to another, such as from development to test, and to production.Can creating packages in the migration manager and promoting them from one environment to another be automated somehow outside of the tool, so say something like a script that can allow to login to the maximo migration manager and then allow to perform the manual steps.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mbs.doc/gp_migmgr/c_ctr_mig_mgr_over.html

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to write an automation script to create the migration manager packages and deploy them to the other environments using the psdi.dm Java package:

https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/7609/maximocore/businessobjects/psdi/dm/DMPackageDef.html

You could then potentially trigger execution of the automation script from outside of the system with an HTTP request:

[Run an automation script via a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58437933/run-an-automation-script-via-a-url)

Alternatively (and separate to Migration Manager) you could automate generation of dbc scripts for product config. changes:

https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/dbcguide/

https://github.com/ibm-maximo-dev/maximo-scripting/blob/master/samples/AS11_importExportScripts.md

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this solution would work. But i am fairly new to Maximo and not much familiar with its core. Is there a way to auto generate a script to create a package and move from an environment to another in maximo migration manager, or do you have a sample script that can do that. I can try to invoke that using the method you suggested using HTTP request.